# Generate quasi-random data for line chart in Java

Tags: java, random

For prototyping and testing, I want to generate fake sets of data for line charts.

Something like Y-axis values between 0 and 99, with X-axis being points in time (every minute). The idea is to have somewhat realistic-looking data, with some curves going up and down gently. Nothing too fancy, just something better that calling [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) which scatters points all over (of course, as it should).

I suppose just generating points along a [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave), would work – except that I've forgotten all my math schooling. Even better would be something like a sine wave but a little bit more randomized.

Can anyone share some code, or point me in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise)

You can find some discussion of this [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61940/sidescrolling-terrain-1d-perlin-noise)

You can find some example source code [here](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~jeremy/atmm/BlockPolly/render/Noise.java) on [Jeremy Weinberger](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~jeremy/)'s page